# How do I create a click and paste button?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension with buttons that paste specific text into an input box. Is it possible to without an HTML file?

Manifest file

```
   {
  "name": "Context Menus Sample",
  "description": "Click & Paste",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus", "tabs"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["sample.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Sample.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('fkbx');

    link.addEventListener('click', function() {
        $("#fkbox").text("hell world");
    });
});
```

[I'm trying to make an extension with menu's like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ9Ki.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description and the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ9Ki.png) you provided, you want to add contextMenus for browser action, take a look at [`chrome.contextMenus.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-create), and you could use the following sample:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: 'Your context menu title',
    contexts: ['browser_action'],
    onclick: YOUR_CLICK_EVENT_HANDLER,
});
```

Answer (score -2):

This should do it.

```js
var mytext  = "text to paste";
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()l
    $('#inputbox').val(mytext);
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <input id='inputbox'>
    <a href="#" id='button' class='button'>click here</a>
    </body>
</html>
```